# LLVM BasicBlock pass

Tags: llvm

I am a beginner of LLVM. I am trying to move among the instructions of a BasicBlock and I cannot. In this particular example, I try to get the previous instruction of the end instruction. I am trying 2 methods:

1. I have the following sequence of code:

   ```
   bool patternDC::runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {
   ...
   if (BB.getTerminator())
     {
               Instruction* current = BB.getTerminator();
               errs() << "\n LAST: "<<*current<<"\n";

           Instruction* prev = &BB.back();
           errs() << "\n PENULTIMATE: "<<*prev<<"\n";         
          ...
   ```

The terminal prints the SAME instruction. I don't know how back() works. (Definition at line 199 of file BasicBlock.h.)

1. I also tried :

   ```
   bool patternDC::runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {
   ...
   BasicBlock::const_iterator I = BB.begin();
   BasicBlock::const_iterator E = BB.end();
   BasicBlock::const_iterator prev_iter,last_iter;
   prev_iter = NULL; last_iter = NULL;
   for(;I!=E;I++){
       prev_iter = last_iter;
       last_iter = I;
   }
   if(prev_iter){
       errs() << "prev_iter: " << *(dyn_cast<Instruction>(prev_iter)) << "\n";
   }
   if(last_iter){
       errs() << "last_iter: " << *(dyn_cast<Instruction>(last_iter)) << "\n";
   }
    // not related to the main question: uncomment the next line for an unusual      
   //behavior: lastlast is DIFFERENT from last.lastlast=section(BasicBlock)
     // errs() << "lastlast: " << *(dyn_cast<Instruction>(I)) << "\n";
     ...
      Instruction* prev = *(dyn_cast<Instruction*>(prev_iter));
       errs() << "\n prev: "<<*prev<<"\n";
   ```

The terminal prints out well prev and last, but I have compilation errors when trying to assign to Instruction* prev
The Clang error is:
".....
/home/alex/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:51:28: error: ‘classof’ is not a member of ‘llvm::Instruction*’"

If someone knows a better way to use any element from the basic block or knows why these are not working, please let me know :)

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved by checking if(BB->size()>1) for a basic block with only an element

Answer (score 1):

All LLVM `Instruction` classes are also `ilist_node`, which means you can query them for the next/previous instruction in the list that holds them (in this case the basic block). More concretely to your question:

```
Instruction* last = BB.getTerminator();
Instruction* prev = last->getPrevNode();
```

See the definition of `ilist_node` in LLVM's source to see the relevant APIs.

Comment: Thank you ! Now I don't have any compilation errors. But now whenever I try to use *prev, at runtime it gets Stack dump error.

Comment: @user1817807: you may have basic blocks with just a single instruction in them. Check `prev` for being NULL.

Comment: Thank you ! I will check every possibility.

Comment: Ok, the main segfault problem is that: when I iterate through the basic blocks of a function, I use arrays of Instruction* pointers. I want to use these arrays afterwards. Maybe LLVM does not protect the addresses when iterate through basic blocks. So: I need to use Instruction array instead of Instruction* arrays. But how can I create llvm::Instruction s just having the Instruction*?

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure I understand your need here, and it may be a wholly different question. But anyway, `Instruction` has a `clone` method if you want to copy it.

Comment: I solved by checking
if(BB->size()>1) for a basic block with only an element


Now debugging the next segfault.